# How to interpolate between curves in matplotlib?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, interpolation, scientific-computing

I am trying to interpolate between the curves where there is white space in between, as can be seen in the plots below. I am using the matploblib library and Python 3 for this. I tried to find some resources online, but couldn't find anything very good for a beginner like myself. As I mentioned I am using matplotlib, but am open to using other libraries (seaborn?) that might be better for this. Thank you!

Update: As suggested in the comments, I tried using the `plt.fill_between()` method, with interpolation=True with a new colormap (viridis). However, the result is below. Something isn't working. Any suggestions? I have attached the code for my plot below.

```
        import Model

        rates = [rate for rate in range(1, 10000, 100)]
        starts = [rates[jj] / 27 for jj in range(len(rates))]
        combo = dict(zip(rates, starts))
        curves = [model.Model(start=combo[rt], R=rt) for rt in combo.keys()]
        for curve in curves:
            curve.run_model()
        to_plot = ['SO4', 'H2S', 'd34S_s', 'd34S_H2S']
        logged = [log(xx) for xx in curves[0].f_in]
        colors = plt.cm.viridis(np.linspace(0, 1, len(rates)))

        for obj in curves:
            for element in to_plot:
                plt.subplot(2, 2, to_plot.index(element) + 1)               
                plt.plot(logged,
                getattr(obj,element),color=colors[curves.index(obj)])
                plt.fill_between(logged, getattr(obj, element), interpolate=True, cmap='viridis')
        sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap='viridis', norm=plt.Normalize(vmin=min(rates), vmax=max(rates)))
        plt.colorbar(sm,label=var)
        plt.show()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You could use [`plt.fill_between()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html). For common colorbars, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html). About avoiding the 'jet' colormap, see [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/colorbar_placement.html).

Comment: Hi @JohanC, thanks for the tip, I am now using the 'viridis' colormap.  I tried using plt.fill_between(), but it does not produce the desired result. Please see my post for the update.

Comment: Well, without code and data to reproduce the image, it is hard to tell what need to change.  You might be interested in reading about [creating reproducible examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @JohanC, sorry, I updated with my code.